# Oracle driver class not found when deploying app to PCF

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g, ojdbc, pcf

I'm trying to deploy my spring boot application to PCF which uses external oracle datasource, the application works fine in local. I have added the ojdbc6.jar in a folder {projectroot}/jars and referenced it in my maven pom.xml file. I am getting the error below:

```
2019-01-17T10:31:11.315+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 
2019-01-17 05:01:11.315 ERROR 16 --- [ main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter :
2019-01-17T10:31:11.315+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ***************************
2019-01-17T10:31:11.315+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] APPLICATION FAILED TO START
2019-01-17T10:31:11.315+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Description:
2019-01-17T10:31:11.315+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:
2019-01-17T10:31:11.315+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Property: driverclassname
2019-01-17T10:31:11.315+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Value: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
2019-01-17T10:31:11.315+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
2019-01-17T10:31:11.315+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Reason: Failed to load driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
```

I have tried installing the ojdbc6 jar using mvn install cmd:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

and added the dependency in my pom file

I have checked the final deployable jar, it contains the ojdbc6.jar in the folder: BOOT-INF/lib

My application.yml file

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbhost:dbport:svcname
    username: username
    password: password
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>odata-example</groupId>
    <artifactId>odata-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>odata-example</name>
    <description>Odata POC for exposing data from DB using Annotation based EDM Objects</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <version.olingo>2.0.8</version.olingo>
    <lombok.version>1.16.18</lombok.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring related dependecies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/jars/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Odata related dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
        <artifactId>olingo-odata2-api</artifactId>
        <version>${version.olingo}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>olingo-odata2-api-annotation</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>${version.olingo}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
        <artifactId>olingo-odata2-core</artifactId>
        <version>${version.olingo}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
        <artifactId>olingo-odata2-annotation-processor-api</artifactId>
        <version>${version.olingo}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
        <artifactId>olingo-odata2-annotation-processor-core</artifactId>
        <version>${version.olingo}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other dependencies -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Is this the right approach to connect to external Oracle DB from pcf and also why it's not able to find driver class if the jar is present in BOOT-INF/lib. Does it look some other location for external jars?

I'm quite new to pcf.

Comment: I believe you need to exclude the hikari artifact from POM.xml.

Comment: thank you, I excluded the hikari artifact and it worked like a charm!!, but I am still not sure why hikari was creating the problem, do you have any idea about that